# MongoDB/Mongoose .find() equal to true/false where null==true

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Trying to simplify this snippet into a one liner.

```
var conditions = [{key: isTrueOrFalse}];
if (isTrueOrFalse)
  conditions.push({key: null});
query.find({$or: conditions});
```

The key, by default, isn't set in the model.

I wrote this util function to make it a one liner, but I'd prefer to use something built into mongoose if possible.

```
var findWithDefaultIfNull = function(query, key, value, defaultValue) {
  var conditions = [];
  var condition = {};
  condition[key] = value;
  conditions.push(condition);
  if (value == defaultValue) {
    condition = {};
    condition[key] = null;
    conditions.push(condition);
  }
  console.log(conditions);
  query.find({$or: conditions});
};
exports.findWithDefaultIfNull = findWithDefaultIfNull;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This, but as a query. Match: `if (model.key === value || (value === defaultValue && model.key === undefined) return true;`